# filter composed of identical sections

Tags: filter

I am trying to follow filter design scheme proposed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06847).

The paper draws an analogy between electrical and mechanical filters.

I think understanding this paper boils down to understanding equation (1)

\$ -1 \leq \frac{Z_1}{4Z_2} \leq 0 \$

and Fig 1

[image]

I understand that the three schematics correspond to three different ways you can break up the building block (unit) of the general scheme.  I am not sure what \$Z_{iter}\$ represents and how they got the expressions in terms of \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$

Answer (score 1):

\$Z_{iter}\$ is the impedance of an infinite series of identical filter sections.

If you take one section away from an infinite series, you still have exactly the same infinite series - infinity minus one is still infinity. Therefore, adding or removing any number of sections must not change the impedance.

Start with an impedance of \$Z_{iter}\$ (which represents the infinite series), add another filter section in front of that, and then recognize that the impedance of this overall circuit is *still* \$Z_{iter}\$. Now the harder part is to actually solve this to find out which value of \$Z_{iter}\$ can be equal to these two impedances at the same time.

Comment: Regarding \$Z_{iter}\$, that is what I thought.  So, for the first case in Fig 1(b), I would have \$Z_{iter} = Z_1 + (\frac{1}{Z_2}+\frac{1}{Z_{iter}})^{-1} \$. When solving for \$Z_{iter}\$, I do get \$Z_{iter}=\frac{Z_1}{2} +\sqrt{Z_1 Z_2 + \frac{Z_{1}^{2}}{4}} \$.  It was my arthmetic mistake.   I still don't understand equation 1 though.  Equation 1 seems to give you the range of frequencies that propagate through the filter (hence, pass-band).  But it's not clear to me how they even got equation 1 to begin with.